# How to fix "plugin with id 'jetty' not found" error?

Tags: gradle, build, jetty

java 1.7
gradle version 7.4.2

When I import gradle project to sts, it gives me an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\test\build.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test'.
> Plugin with id 'jetty' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 121ms
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhGiX.png)

I tried to change line number 4 **apply plugin: 'jetty'** to
**apply plugin: 'org.gretty'**
or
**apply plugin: 'com.dsvdsv.gradle.plugin'**
or
**apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'**

but it didn't work.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Caution.  The last version of Jetty that supported Java 1.7 was Jetty 9.2, and it was declared End of Life back in 2018 (and has no fixes for the changes in Google Chrome since then) - https://eclipse.dev/jetty/download.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
plugins {
  id("org.gretty") version "4.0.3"
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?